# Prototype chain of History object?

Tags: javascript

Which one is correct?

Chrome returns false

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(history)) === Object.prototype
false
```

Fireforx return true

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(history)) === Object.prototype
true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both.

[The specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#the-history-interface) doesn't precise the type of the object or how the browser creates it, but only an interface.